# Fast way to simulate operations on a matrix

Tags: algorithm

This is from an old Olympiad practice problem:

Imagine you have a 1000x1000 grid, in which the cell (i,j) contains the number i*j.  (Rows and columns are numbered starting at 1.)

At each step, we build a new grid from the old one, in which each cell (i,j) contains the "neighborhood average" of (i,j) in the last grid.  The "neighborhood average" is defined as the floor of the average values of the cell and its up to 8 neighbors.  So for example if the 4 numbers in the corner of the grid were 1,2,5,7, in the next step the corner would be calculated as (1+2+5+7)/4 = 3.

Eventually we'll reach a point where all the numbers are the same and the grid doesn't change anymore.  The goal is to figure out how many steps it takes to reach this point.

I tried simply simulating it but that doesn't work, because it seems that the answer is O(n^2) steps and each simulation step takes O(n^2) to process, resulting in O(n^4) which is too slow for n=1000.

Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried starting with smaller grids (say 5 to 20)? Odds are a pattern should form allowing you to calculate the number of steps for any grid size using a formula. This sounds like the kind of problem that requires a mathematical optimization rather than a programming one.

Comment: I wrote all the step counts (let's call it f(n)) for n=1 to 200, and didn't find any pattern.  I even tried writing f(n)-f(n-1) and didn't see a pattern other than it generally grows at an O(n) rate.  It looks pretty random.

Comment: Do you have a rough definition of "too slow"? 1 trillion iterations is a lot, especially depending on the speed of each iteration... But it is not "lifetime of the universe" magnitude. How fast does this need to be?

Comment: @Nemo The problem set was designed to be solved within a 4-hour time frame, and it only required the output, so basically anything that would work within an hour or so would be reasonable.  By my estimates, just running the simulation would take more than 4 hours.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: That starts to sound like a micro-optimization task... I think you can reduce the computation substantially by reusing intermediate results from the previous row. Let me write up some ideas as an answer.

Comment: @Nemo, It could possibly be an optimization task, but it needs something better than just halving the number of operations.  If for example we could eliminate the factor of 8 required to add neighbors that would probably be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "floor" step makes me suspect an analytical solution is unlikely, and that this actually a micro-optimization exercise. Here is my idea.

Let's ignore the corners and edges for a moment. There are only 3996 of them and they will need special treatment anyway.

For an interior cell, you need to add 9 elements to get its next state. But turn that around, and say: Each interior cell has to be part of 8 additions.

Or does it? Start with three consecutive rows `A[i]`, `B[i]`, and `C[i]`, and compute three new rows:

```
A'[i] = A[i-1] + A[i] + A[i+1]
B'[i] = B[i-1] + B[i] + B[i+1]
C'[i] = C[i-1] + C[i] + C[i+1]
```

(Note that you can compute each of these slightly faster with a "sliding window", since `A'[i+1] = A'[i] - A[i-1] + A[i+1]`. Same number of arithmetic operations but fewer loads.)

Now, to get the new value at location `B[j]`, you just compute `A'[j] + B'[j] + C'[j]`.

So far, we have not saved any work; we have just reordered the additions.

But now, having computing the updated row `B`, you can throw away `A'` and compute the next row:

```
D'[i] = D[i-1] + D[i] + D[i+1]
```

...which you can use with arrays `B'` and `C'` to compute the new values for row `C` without recomputing `B'` or `C'`. (You would implement this by shifting row `B'` and `C'` to become `A'` and `B'`, of course... But this way was easier to explain. Maybe. I think.)

For each row, say `B`, we scan it once to produce `B'` doing `2n` arithmetic operations, and a second time to compute the updated `B` which also takes `2n` operations, so in total we do four additions/subtractions per element instead of eight.

Of course, in practice, you would compute `C'` while updating `B` for the same number of operations but better locality.

That's the only structural idea I have. A SIMD optimization expert might have other suggestions...

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly faster way can be as follows:

If you notice for any cell that is not on the matrix border (x,y), it's original value shall be x*y.

Also, the value of the cell after 1st iteration shall be:

```
V1 = (  xy    +    x(y+1)   +   x(y-1)
    +(x+1)y  + (x+1)(y+1)  + (x+1)(y-1)
    +(x-1)y  + (x-1)(y+1)  + (x-1)(y-1)
     ) / 9
   = xy
```

For the elements on the left vertical edge (not on the corners)

```
v2 = ( xy  + (x-1)y + (x+1)y + x(y+1) + (x-1)(y+1) + (x+1)(y+1) ) / 6
   = xy + x/2.
```

For the elements on the right vertical edge (not on the corners)

```
v3 = ( xy  + (x-1)y + (x+1)y + x(y-1) + (x-1)(y-1) + (x+1)(y-1) ) / 6
   = xy - x/2.
```

Similarly for top and bottom horizontal edges and corners.

**Hence after the 1st iteration, only the border elements shall change their value, the non-border elements shall remain the same.**

For subsequent iterations, this change shall be propagated from the borders inwards in the matrix.

So one obvious way you can reduce your computations a little is to only change those elements that you expect to get changed in the first N/2 iterations. **Note:** by doing this the complexity shall not change IMO but the constant factor shall reduce.

Another possible way that you can consider is as follows:

You know that the centre-most element shall be unchanged till N/2 iterations.

So you may think of a way to jumptstart your iterations by starting from the centre-most element outwards.

That it, if you can find out an **incremental** mathematical formula for the change in elements after N/2 iterations, you may reduce the complexity of your algorithm by a factor of N.

Comment: @templatetypedef Thanks, but I think this can be used in a better way than proposed by me. Needs some careful thought.

Comment: The formulas can be compacted even more into the form `Axy + Bx + Cy + D`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  It's true that initially most numbers won't change; however by running it on smaller values such as n=100 and writing down what % of values change in each iteration, it seems that in most iterations (besides the first few and last few) the number of elements changed is 40-60% so I was unable to to make use of this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the initial matrix you'll notice that it's [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Properties) i.e. m[i][j] = m[j][i]. Therefore the neighbors of m[i][j] will have the same values as the neighbors of m[j][i], so you only need to calculate values for a little more than half the matrix for each step.

This optimization reduces the # of calculations per grid from `N^2` to `((N^2)+N)/2`.

Comment: In my tests, the center element does indeed change.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman for which odd value of n are you seeing the center element change?

Comment: Pretty much all of them.  n=5 for example, the center starts at 9 and ends at 4.  It doesn't happen in the beginning, but generally you get a low number propagate rightward and downward from the top-left corner until it fills the entire grid.